# VBA: Naming a Range

Tags: vba, named-ranges

I have searched for a solution but can't seem to find one. If one exists, please point me to it.
The question is how do I name a range in VBA.

```
    wrkSheet.Range("A1").Name = "Test"
```

Works fine but as soon as I change it to

```
    wrkSheet.Range("A1:B2").Name = "Test"
```

gives me problems. Note, wrkSheet is a worksheet object that is defined earlier.

Thanks

Comment: "gives me problems" means what exactly?  `wrkSheet` is really a string, or is it a worksheet object?  If it's a string then you want `Sheets(wrkSheet).Range("A1:B2").Name = "Test"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this to name a range.  Not sure why wrkSheet is a string as it should be a worksheet object

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim r As Range
Set ws = Sheets(1)
Set r = ws.Range("A1:B2")
r.Name = "test"
```

Comment: the code works great!. As a follow up question, I want to have something like r.Name = "test_" & some_string but I am getting a problem. Any ideas?

Comment: Try r.Name = "test_" + some_string

Answer (score 0):

You're not naming a range there... you giving values to a excel range of cells...
To name a range you do

```
range = wrkSheet.Range("A1:B2").Name
```

Then you can do `range(1,1) = "test"` for example.